# Switch observable on condition

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have two observables and I want to use the first one unless it doesn't give me what I want (in this case an empty list). If that's the case I wwant to switch to the second one.

```
fun test() {

    listSource1().switchMap {
        if (it.isEmpty()) listSource2() else listSource1()
    }

}

fun listSource1() = Observable.just(emptyList<String>())

fun listSource2() = Observable.just(listOf("hello"))
```

Is there a better way than this? it seems strange to map `listSource1` to `listSource1`, is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlatMap the first to see if the item is an empty list:

```java
Observable<List<T>> source = ...

Observable<List<T>> fallbackSource = ...

source.flatMap(list -> {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return fallbackSource;
    }
    return Observable.just(list);
});
```